# Mulitple Modal Popups not working in IE 7

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have two modal popups on a page, both inside user controls, and both have different names, and different behavior id's. Also, the hidden buttons used with them have different id's. I use javascript to click those buttons to show the popup.

On load of the page, the first popup is hidden, but the second one is not, and is at the bottom of the page completely visible. When I click the link that is supposed to show the second popup, the first one is shown instead, but the javascript to load the default values into the first popup does not run, so I'm confused as to what is going on. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post code, a jsfiddle, or a link to the site. Otherwise we don't really have much to go on to troubleshoot.

Comment: Need to see some sort of code to even begin to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. My situation is bit different. for you both pop ups are in a user control. But for me only one is in user control and other one is in the page itself. hope this will shed some light on your issue.

I gave different id's for

- Hidden Target button (TargetControlID)
- OK button (OkControlID)
- Popup Panel  (pnlPopup)
- Model Popup control

Still if you are not sure, try your page in firefox with firebug installed. This will help you to identify any java-script errors.

Hope this helps.